# Overlay Input on <p> or <div>

Tags: html, css

Hopefully an easy question.

I have a `<p>` which has some styling on it to make it look like a UK registration plate.

I want to overlay an input field so the user can type in a reg.

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/zZUDN/)

I'm struggling to get the overlay even when changing elements to absolute.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <p class="reg">007 ABC</p>
   <input id="vehicleReg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Vehicle Registration" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.reg {
background-color: #ec0;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ec0, #ca0);
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
font-family: number_plate;
display: inline-block;
/*padding: 0 50px 0 100px;*/
width: 220px;
position: relative;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 50px;
/*margin: 100px;*/
color: black;
/*    text-indent: 10px;*/
}

.reg::after {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
color: #ec0;
content: "\25CC";
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 32px;
left: 0;
height: 50%;
line-height: 70px;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 14px;
position: absolute;
}

.vehicleReg { 
position: absolute;
right: 13%;
bottom: 17px;
width: 64%;
height: 31px;
background-color: transparent;
text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to get the input field on top of the reg plate? if so what will happen to the text in the p?

Comment: `.vehicleReg` element does not exist in your markup, only `#vehicleReg`

Comment: I think you are doing it the wrong way, just change the text of the <p> tag on _keypress_ of the input field.

Comment: @Pete - Yes, on top of the reg plate.. The text in p would disappear.

Comment: @Sasidharan - Your comment adds no value at all. For someone with a decent rep, i am surprised you respond to queries like this. For future reference, before you belittle people, you should understand why the user has used both classes and id's.

Comment: @Oam Psy,on seeing your comment, i was searching what i have commented on ua post.Did i mean anything wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit slow but the following will keep your little euro image and put the input above your top fade:

**html**

```
<div class="reg"><input id="vehicleReg" type="text" placeholder="Reg No" /></div>
```

**css**

```
.reg {
    background-color: #ec0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ec0, #ca0);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    display: inline-block;
    /*padding: 0 50px 0 100px;*/
    width: 220px;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 100px;*/
    color: black;
/*    text-indent: 10px;*/
    text-align:center
}

.reg::after {
    text-align:left;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
    color: #ec0;
    content: "\25CC";
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    line-height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 14px;
    position: absolute;
}

#vehicleReg { 
   width: 70%;
    margin:auto;
   background-color: transparent;
    border:0;
    font-family: number_plate;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative; z-index:2;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zZUDN/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you could style the placeholder text.

```
placeholder {
font-family: number_plate;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 28px;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:black;
text-align:center;
```

}

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nQDN2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are positioning the input absolutely, you'll need to make it relative to a container div, in this case.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="reg">007 ABC</p>
  <input id="vehicleReg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Vehicle Registration" />
</div>

.container { 
   position: relative;
}
```

See this: 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zZUDN/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zZUDN/8/

```
<div class="reg">
    <input id="vehicleReg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Vehicle Registration" />
</div>

.reg {
  border:none;
  background-color: #ec0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ec0, #ca0);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  font-family: number_plate;
  display: inline-block;
  /*padding: 0 50px 0 100px;*/
  width: 220px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  /*margin: 100px;*/
  color: black;
  /*    text-indent: 10px;*/
}

.reg::after {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  color: #ec0;
  content: "\25CC";
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  line-height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 14px;
  position: absolute;
}

#vehicleReg { 
  width:100%;
  line-height:45px;
  font-size:28px;
  border:none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: @OamPsy would just like to point out this doesn't have your lighter top half and you cannot click on the top half of the input

Comment: @Pete Aha, didn't even notice the colour difference

Comment: @OamPsy I'd agree with Pete, change to accept his answer if you can as my styling was only half complete

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unrelated but if you are after the user to type in a registration plate number look into using the input attribute pattern and give it a max length of 8 characters.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[ ][A-Za-z]{3}" maxlength="8" />
```

That enforces the pattern that a registration requires 4 alphanumeric characters a space and 3 characters.

(Part of HTML5 only works in latest browsers. IE are slow to catch up)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.vehicleReg { 
 position: absolute;
 right: 13%;
 bottom: 17px;
 width: 64%;
 height: 31px;
 background-color: transparent;
 text-align:center;
}
```

to

```
#vehicleReg { 
 position: absolute;
 right: 13%;
 bottom: 17px;
 width: 64%;
 height: 31px;
 background-color: transparent;
 text-align:center;
}
```

*vehicleReg* is the id of the input field, not the class.